# Jmeter Retry Request if failed or ResponseCode not equal to 200

Tags: while-loop, jmeter, request, http-response-codes, extractor

I have a CSV File with hundreds of records which I am using in the HTTP Sampler with Multiple Threads now sometime or multiple threads returns an error which I am OK but I want to retry in case we don't have ResponseCode 200 which I am extracting but not sure how to retry just that Request only and also I want to limit the tries to 5

I have tried using the while controller with Counter but somehow not able to get this right. Please help.

This is what I have tried
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Added the steps screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to define the `Exported Variable Name` in the Counter otherwise it doesn't make any sense:

   [image]
2. You need to use [`vars` shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) in your __groovy() function to get both `Counter` and `Success` variables values

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('Status') != 'Success' && (vars.get('Counter') as int) < 5,)}
   ```
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider replacing your Beanshell Assertion with [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)

Comment: Thanks your solution worked for 1 record only so what I did was I executed HTTP Sampler outside the while and then I added if controller only if the above Request Failed and inside if I added the while controller which worked fine. Unless you have a smart idea without IF Controller I am happy with the solution

Answer (score 0):

add the following to `while controller ${__javaScript(parseInt(vars.get("Response_code"))!=200)}`

add the relevant request inside while controller

add `JSR223 PostProcessor` for the above request and, add the following code inside "JSR223 PostProcessor"
`vars.put("Response_code",prev.getResponseCode());`

set `Response_code` variable in `user defined variables`